# WCF service message security

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, x509certificate

I have a problem with message security in WCF. I'm using this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96028/WCF-Service-with-custom-username-password-authenti 
I have 2 services. First one, with wshttpbindig is OK. Second one, with wsdualhttpbinding doesn't work. I have an exception when I'm opening proxy after setting Credentials. It looks like I have to set Credentials before I open proxy, but I can't open proxy after set Credentials. I was using only one certificate for both services.

What I should do with this?
When I have 2 services do I have to use 2 certificates? If yes how can I do it?

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);                    
proxy = new CommunicationServiceReference.CommunicationServiceClient(context);

_proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserSession.Login;
_proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = UserSession.Password;
_proxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
_proxy.Endpoint.Address.Uri.Port.ToString();

_proxy.Open();
```

EDIT:
Is it possible to configure service with wsdualhttpbinding using tutorial i posted above?

Comment: Wrap the `_proxy.Open()` call in an exception handler and check what exception (if any) is being raised).

Comment: In client's appconfig I deacreased open timeout time and application threw timeout exception. It's freezes on this line.